# Error for timeIntervalSinceNow using to pause and resume timer

Tags: iphone

Using pause timer and resume timer in my code to pause and resume timer. Got error 
`'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber timeIntervalSinceNow]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x164590'`

code for pause timer and resume timer

```
-(void)pauseTimer{
pauseStart = [[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0] retain];
previousFireDate = [[timer fireDate] retain];
[timer setFireDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
}
-(void)resumeTimer{
float pauseTime = -1*[pauseStart timeIntervalSinceNow];
[timer setFireDate:[previousFireDate initWithTimeInterval:pauseTime sinceDate:previousFireDate]];
[pauseStart release];
[previousFireDate release];
}
```

Using pause and resume timer in play pause toggle button

```
-(void)playpauseAction:(id)sender {
if([audioPlayer isPlaying])
{
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Play Icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [audioPlayer pause];
    [self pauseTimer];
}
else
{
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [audioPlayer play];
    [self resumeTimer];
    if(isFirstTime == YES)
    {
        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:11.0
                                            target:self
                                            selector:@selector(displayviewsAction:)
                                            userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:NO];
        isFirstTime  = NO;
    }    
} 
}
```

Any idea why app terminated and how to fix this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `resumeTimer` is called twice `pauseStart` and `previousFireDate` get overreleased and the application can crash!

Comment: can you help me what is fix for this because i m getting memory leak for pause timer and release timer if i m using it for multiple times. What is the fix for this.

Comment: i would create a new timer instance and invalidate the old one